# How to define nginx code for per Domain?

Tags: nginx

My /etc/nginx/nginx.conf code is :

```
server { 
..... 
location / { 
root /var/www/public_folder; 
index index.php index.html index.htm; 
} 
. 
. 
. 
}
```

and my created Domain config file is: 
nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/definedname.com

```
server { 

listen 80 default; 
listen 443 http2 default_server; 
listen [::]:443 http2 default_server; 

server_name definedname.com www.definedname.com; 
root /var/www/public_folder/definedname.com/$host; 

..... 
}
```

when I want to go to my first page, I see global configuration index.html text, who defined within the global configuration route in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf , this text show in my domain first page

What is my mistake exactly?

Comment: you can use nginx virtual hosts and for every host you can set a dedicated document root.

Comment: @c4f4t0r Hi , could you please give me a learning method within an external Link

Comment: In few wors, when you use server_name with many values in the same virtualhost, that means that you use the same code for this site, if your sites are differents is better that you create separated vhosts https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Comment: `listen 80 default;` is this a typo? There is no `default` parameter for `listen` directive, there is a `default_server`.